# Once mixed, how long is cake batter good when refrigerated?

Tags: cake

After using a cake mix to bake in a lamb shaped form, I have batter left over. How long can I keep it refrigerated (not frozen) and still combine it with another cake mix batter -- and have the second cake bake properly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing cake batter](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/41959/storing-cake-batter)

Comment: Welcome to the site @TheOwl, your question has already been asked, please see the link above.

Comment: @GdD I don't think this is quite a duplicate.  That question asks about storing and using just the batter that was stored.  This question indicates that OP wants to mix saved batter in with fresh batter, which I think might behave differently (or at least the situation is different enough to warrant a more tailored answer).

Comment: The second box of mix would give fresh leavening (baking powder or whatever), so it might be okay ... but I suspect it'd be a little bit more dense than usual.  But I still wouldn't try to keep it for more than day or two in the fridge.  Eggs and milk, and exposed to the elements by stirring.

Answer (score 1):

Comments are right, mixing with another box would probably not provide enough leavening for the second cake to be successful.  Just toss the leftover batter into a smaller baking  pan.  You'd be better off having a very slightly stale mini-cake the second day than a larger fresher brick.  A bit of fruit and whipped cream would disguise the not-baked-today character very effectively.  Or you could just eat it before the guests arrive :-)